# Can't get curl to submit a simple content-type in drupal-7

Tags: php, curl, drupal, drupal-7

I have to make a script that logins to a drupal 7 user and upload content(no admin or database access).I have used cURL and successfully logged in and also saved session id cooky.Afterwards I can access the content-type form page, successfuly(indicates that cooky is stored) but the form never submits successfully.Here is my code

```
$crl = curl_init();
$url = "http://example.com/drupal/content/node/add/simple";
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt"); 
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$postdata = array(
"title"=>"dokimastiki anartisi",
"form_id"=>"simple_node_form",
"name"=>"dimitris",
"body[und][0][format]"=>"filtered_html",
"name"=>"dimitris",
"form_id"=>"simple_node_form",
"op"=>"Send message",);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$result=curl_exec($crl);
$headers = curl_getinfo($crl);
echo curl_exec($crl);
session_write_close();
curl_close($crl);
```

I ve been strugling to make this work for 2 days.I have tried adding name and default values of every form element.Can anyone see any obvious mistakes I make? Thank you

Comment: If you  have struggle with curl on your own, did you think about trying [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)? Might be easier and a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I will look into it if nothing else works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thought drupal automatically created CSRF protection tokens that you have to append to every POST request? you provide no code to fetch a csrf token prior to posting, i bet that's your problem. what does the request look like in the browser?

Comment: In browser I see the add/content page with the fields I 've specified in my code along with an error message saying "The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page."

Comment: @DimitrisPolitis and what does the request look like? what's the name of all the post data parameters?

Comment: here": "title"=>"title",
"changed"=>"",
"form_build_id"=>"xxx",
"form_token"=>"xxx",
"form_id"=>"simple_node_form",
"body[und][0][summary]"=>"",
"revision" =>"1",
"comment"=>"2",
"path[pathauto]"=>"1",
"path[alias]"=>"",
"name"=>"dimitris",
"date"=>"",
"status"=>"",
"promote"=>"1",
"sticky"=>"1",
"status"=>"1",
"additional_settings__active_tab"=>"",
"additional_settings__active_tab"=>"",
"body[und][0][summary]"=>
"body[und][0][format]"=>
"op"=>

Comment: @DimitrisPolitis as i thought, your problem is definitely the form_token, it changes on each request, and if you send the wrong one, or if you don't send one at all, the server will reject your request, thinking it's a `cross-site request forgery` hacking attempt. you'll first have to fetch the page generating the token, parse out the token from the html, and add that to your post request, with the accompanying cookie id.

Comment: @DimitrisPolitis if you can show me the url, i can probably make an example implementation for you

Comment: I appriciate your help a lot.Do you know how I could retreive the token since file_get_content says 403:Access Forbident and curl won't output any html without running crl_exec (wich outdates the token)?

Comment: @DimitrisPolitis use curl to retrieve the token and the cookie session. use DOMDocument to parse out the token. note, if you put CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to emptystring, curl will handle cookies for you automatically, that's what i always do.

Comment: I ve sucessfully uploaded content to my site! I didnt managed to use DOMDocument though.I made a 'clean' curl_exec withoud any post data and then searched through the resulted html with explode().Its kinda unprofessional, I would have liked to use DOM but kept getting errors,still works though. Thank you very much for your help, wouldnt have done it without your guidance.